# SqlCommand connection string for localhost database

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to create a simple website in VS Express for Web 2013 which can interact with a database "Parts." My database is stored in the app_data folder. I am able to view the connection in the Server Explorer, which implies the connection string is saved. However, the following code throws 2 errors:

1. Error   13  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments
2. Error   14  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

I don't know how to remedy this. Here is my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void insertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstring =     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PARTS VALUES('" + nameBox.Text + "', '" + descriptionBox.Text + "', '" + quantityBox.Text + "', '" + categoryList.SelectedValue + "')", connstring);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I'm completely new to c#, so please keep that in mind. Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: The following code throws two errors, both of which are:

```
Error   15  The name 'conn' does not exist in the current context
```

I'm new to c#, but it doesn't look like there's anything wrong with the code. The name "conn" is clearly defined right above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void insertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO PARTS VALUES(@name, @description, @quantity, @category)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", nameBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", descriptionBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("quantity", quantityBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("category", categoryList.SelectedValue);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    // use conn to create the command
}
```

But important: YOUR SQL IS REALLY REALLY DANGEROUS. That is open to SQL injection, a HUGE and trivially easy attack surface. Please please parameterize that.

For example:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO PARTS VALUES(@name, @description, ...)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", nameBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", descriptionBox.Text);
    //...
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

(note you need to add a few yourself; I have left it incomplete, just `name` and `description` used for example)

Comment: For some reason, when I use your code,this happens:
 "Error 16 The name 'conn' does not exist in the current context" for "conn.Open()"

Comment: @Johnny_Rose did you accidentally add a `{}` after the first `using` statement?

Comment: No, the updated code is posted. I may have just done something stupid, but it's hard to tell given my lack of c# expertise.

Comment: @Johnny you added a semicolon to the first using statement (far right). Remove it.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Now I'm getting the following exception:
"Server Error in '/' Application. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The error is somewhere on this line (or rather, this line is highlighted): "Line 14:         using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString))"

Comment: @Johnny_Rose that suggests there is no connection string called "conne‌ct" in the config file, so `ConnectionStrings["connect"]` is returning `null`

Answer (score 2):

What is connect value from your config?

Can you try

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

and now issue the query.

Comment: A note on how parameterized queries would help this answer as the OP is open to sql injection

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `SqlConnection` first:

```
string connstring =     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PARTS VALUES('" + nameBox.Text + "', '" + descriptionBox.Text + "', '" + quantityBox.Text + "', '" + categoryList.SelectedValue + "')"
                               , conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Some early habits to get into:

- Do not concatenate SQL strings.  This is for several reasons, not the least of which is the vulnerability to SQL Injection attacks.
- wrap your connection and command in `using` statements.  That ensures that the connections are closed properly if there is an exception.

The end result will look something like:

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO PARTS VALUES(@name, @description, @quantity, @categoryList)"
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql , conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameBox.Text);
        ... etc.

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't throw any exceptions, however, it doesn't insert a new value into my table either. Is there something else I need to look at?

Comment: What database are you using?  If using a local database is it getting copied or rebuilt when you build?

Comment: It's a local database. A little box popped up (which I didn't notice the first time) and says "NullReferenceException was not handled by user code." The highlighted line is "string connstring =     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;"

Comment: Sounds like your connection string isn't in the app.config file (or doesn't have the key `"connect"`